# How to add product image to new order email template

Tags: magento2, product-images, order-email

I need to add a `product image` to a `new order email` after successful checkout.

Which file do I need to **override** to affect only **new order email template**?

Should I override it in `app/code` or `app/design`?

**Can anyone suggest a proper way to do it!?**

Answer (score 1):

As you want to follow the best approach then you have to use the ***modular approach***  means create a module under **app/code** and do what override template and add new class whatever your needs.

If you want to override add the **image as new column** like ***Items,Qty,Price***, then you have rewrite `Magento_Sales::email/items.phtml` from your module, and you have to copy all code of `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml` and past at your module items.phtml.

Create `sales_email_order_items.xml` `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/` and rewrite override code at here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" >
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="items" template="MyVendor_MyModule::email/items.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

and templates **items.phtml** file location `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/email`

**Note that you have to copy all code of `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml` and past at your module items.phtml**.

Now, you have to render **the image** to **phtml**  file means `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml`

So, you have to override the `default.phtml` , but before want to create a helper class where I will create a method which product image path.

Answer (score 0):

Copy following file

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

In this file you have ordered item information. You can add image by load product by id and get image from product object.

Please let me know still if you have any question.